# Match all lines which contain string but do not contain other string (with regular expression)

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this 3 lines, starting with **`<p class="sd-23">`**. The second line does not contain the closing tag **`</p>`**

So, I need to use a regex as to find all lines which contain **`<p class="sd-23">`** but does not contain the closing tag **`</p>`**

```
<p class="sd-23">Somebody to love</p>

<p class="sd-23">In 1495, the Grand Prince gave this icon as a blessing to his daughter Helen.

<p class="sd-23">Holy Birth of God, have mercy on us!</p>
```

I really don't know why my regex not working:

**FIND:**

**`(?<p class="sd-23">).*(?!</p>)`**

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(<p class="sd-23">)((?!</p>).)*$`
- Replace with: `$0</p>`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>